# How to send files instead of just text into JMS queue?

Tags: java, jms

I just downloaded and installed WebSphere MQ 8.x (in my Windows 7). Now I want to learn *how to send and receive files*.

The WebSphere MQ installation comes with some code samples (`C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere MQ\Tools\jms\sample\JmsProducer.java`), but all them (in the `/Tools` directory) use message(s) as a `String` (to send and receive).

I would like to send and receive files to/from a JMS queue.

UPDATE:

I started using this :

```
BytesMessage bytes = session.createBytesMessage();
String codePage = CCSID.getCodepage(((MQDestination) destination)
           .getIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CCSID));
bytes.writeBytes("In the destination code page".getBytes(codePage));
producer.send(bytes);
```

but I got this error :
The method getIntProperty(String) is undefined for the type MQDestination

Comment: A file is a container for the content you can send (as a text, object or any other type of information) into a JMS queue. The overhead is that you need to parse/read the file information, store it somewhere and send it to the JMS queue. I've never seen anyone sending a file into a JMS queue since there are better ways to achieve that when handling I/O with files. Are you sure you "want to send a file" into a JMS queue?

Comment: any MQ 8 API that can send/receive files from/to a queue, I never used JMS, just when I found the sample example I was looking if there is any way to tweak it to send files instead of a text string message, I will appreciated if you can give an example on how to do it. Thanks.

Comment: OK, can you use a `BytesMessage`? Then you can read the bytes from your file, place them in that type of message, send it over the queue...and do the opposite when receive it

Comment: I added an UPDATE in my question, I got an error.

Comment: What type are these files as well?  The use of CCSID shouldn't actually be required unless you wish to do some conversion of the files if they are text. 

If you have a larger file based transfer requirements then there is a additional licensable part of MQ - which is an enterprise file transfer solution.

Answer (score 0):

Could you show us the code where you inatanciate "destination" ? the casting to "MQDestination" seems to indicate it is not an instance of JMS "Destination" class
It seems you are mixing JMS and MQ proprietary classes/paradigm